# How can Growl trigger an shell script or AppleScript (NOT vice versa!)

Tags: applescript, script, customization, growl

When a `Growl` notification gets issued I want to trigger an AppleScript. I had a look at the "Actions" in the `Growl` preferences, and you can trigger things like an email or a text-to-speech call, but not an arbitrate shell script  or AppleScript.

Any idea how to do this? Does a `Growl` plugin for this exists? I searched the net for it, but could only find solutions for the other way around (i.e. issuing a notification from a script).

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Growl 2.1 does support ScriptActions, but it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere but a [google group thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/growldiscuss/D6dHxugkUwk/hR8MsVKg7f8J). Below is a simple example from the thread. You create a script file with the content, place it in `~/Library/Application Scripts/com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp`, and then set it up inside Growl as described in the same thread.

```
using terms from application "Growl"
    on perform action with notification
        ignoring case
            if notification's app name is "test growl" then
                activate me
                display dialog "goodbye" with icon 1
            end if
        end ignoring
    end perform action
end using terms from
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support in Growl for this feature, but [according to this Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/growldiscuss/yXKhxmsUkSI/EWbXvdITMZMJ):

> Growl 2.1 will be bringing a Script action capable of running either 
>   shell scripts or AppleScripts.  This will be a 10.8+ feature though as 
>   Growl 2.0+ is sandboxed, and the tool we need to run arbitrary user 
>   scripts while under sandboxing is a 10.8+ feature.

Growl 2.1 is still in Alpha testing.